# Why my strace command is not working with fish?

Tags: fish

I'm trying to launch a command that I'm able to launch with Bash but not with Fish :

- On **Bash** this is working well :

```sh
$ sudo strace -f -s3000 -p $(pgrep -f teams -d " -p ") -o /tmp/debug.log
strace: Process 49774 attached with 32 threads
strace: Process 49778 attached
strace: Process 49780 attached
strace: Process 49817 attached with 10 threads
strace: Process 49824 attached with 6 threads
strace: Process 49848 attached with 13 threads
strace: Process 55055 attached with 6 threads
strace: Process 56914 attached with 17 threads
strace: Process 56965 attached with 44 threads
strace: Process 57041 attached with 10 threads
```

- On **Fish** i'm trying the same but without the '$' but I got an error :

```sh
$ sudo strace -f -s3000 -p (pgrep -f teams -d " -p ") -o /tmp/debug.log
strace: Invalid process id: '-p'
```

This strace is to follow all the processes of Teams, here is the pgrep command only (for info) :

```sh
$ pgrep -f teams -d " -p "
49774 -p 49778 -p 49780 -p 49817 -p 49824 -p 49848 -p 55055 -p 56914 -p 56965 -p 57041
```

Any idea ?

Comment: No in my second example i'm using Fish not Bash

Comment: Sorry for the noise!

Comment: `fish` doesn't apply word-splitting to the result of the command substitution. The argument to the single `strace` option `-p` is `49774 -p 49778 ...`, rather than `strace` receiving multiple `-p` options.

Comment: Any idea to bypass that word-splitting problem ?

Comment: I figured it out, but it's bit complicated :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike bash, fish splits command substitutions on *newlines* only, not spaces or tabs or anything else.

This means when your `9774 -p 49778 -p 49780` is passed to `strace` as *one argument*, where you want it to be five - `9774`, `-p`, `49778`, `-p`, `49780`.

The solution is to just split it explicitly with `string split`:

```
sudo strace -f -s3000 -p (pgrep -f teams -d " -p " | string split " ") -o /tmp/debug.log
```

Comment: it didn't work for me :

```
$ sudo strace -f -s3000 -p (pgrep -f teams -d " -p " | string split " ") -o /tmp/debug.log
strace: Invalid process id: '-o'
$ sudo strace -f -s3000 -p (pgrep -f teams -d " -p " | string split " ")
strace : l'option requiert un argument -- p
Try 'strace -h' for more information.
```

Comment: This means that the inner `pgrep` matched nothing, so your commandline is now `sudo strace -f -s3000 -p -o /tmp/debug.log`. That means the `-p` isn't followed by a PID. Did you forget to start teams?

Comment: I tested quickly, you're right, I hadn't started Teams :p

Answer (score 0):

You could build up the command options in pieces:

```
set opts -f -s3000 -o /tmp/file
for pid in (pgrep -f team); set opts $opts -p $pid; end

sudo strace $opts
```

This takes advantage of the list nature of fish variables.

Comment: Nice, I found another way but it's a bit complicated too.

First, I need to set pgrep in a variable and to do a string split by space
```
$ set PGREP (string split ' ' (pgrep -f teams -d " -p"))
```
Then I call it with : 
```
$ sudo strace -f -s3000 -p $PGREP -o /tmp/debug.log
```
The point is, that's really not easy to remember (I often execute this command) maybe there is another way to automatically set string split to call a variable with Fish

Comment: If this is something you do often, put it in a function.

Answer (score 0):

First, set pgrep in a variable and do a string split with spaces

```
$ set PROCS (string split ' ' (pgrep -f teams -d " -p"))
```

Then call it with :

```
$ sudo strace -f -s3000 -p $PROCS -o /tmp/debug.log
```