# Brace expansion as flag argument pairs

Tags: fish

I'm trying to use `top` in conjunction with `pgrep` to filter the processes that are being shown. What I have working so far is:

```sh
top -pid (pgrep dart)
```

Which works great for getting a single process to show in `top`'s interactive view.

However, the macos version of `top` only has one way of listing multiple processes, you have to just repeat `-pid [process id]` again and again eg:

```sh
top -pid 354 -pid 236 -pid 287
```

My first thought was that I could use brace expansion and command substitution to achieve this, and I tried:

```sh
top "-pid "{(pgrep dart)}
```

But I get `invalid option or syntax: -pid {33978}`. Even when I manually add in pids it doesn't work:

```
top "-pid "{45, 23}

invalid option or syntax: -pid 45
```

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do with fish? i.e insert flags into a command via a combination of command substitution and brace expansion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my strace command is not working with fish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155978/why-my-strace-command-is-not-working-with-fish)

Comment: It does, as it's the same as the answerer of this question suggested (using `string split`). Unfortunately it's not that easy to search for this kind of problem, but I wish i'd have found that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking we can come up with something more concise, but at least:

```
top (string split " " (printf " -p %s" (pgrep dart)))
```

seems to work for me on `fish` on Ubuntu/WSL as a first attempt.  That should translate to:

```
top (string split " " (printf " -pid %s" (pgrep dart)))
```

on MacOS, but from the comments, it sounds like the  `-pid` may be getting passed to `printf` (first), and then `string split`, which neither like, of course.  On WSL/Ubuntu, I ran into that problem, but was able to resolve it by adding the space at the *beginning* of the string.  However, that appears to not be working for Mac.  Your solution is really the more canonical one; use `--` to stop those commands from interpreting the `-pid` as intended for them.

So, `top (string split -n " " -- (printf -- "-pid %s " (pgrep dart)))` works for MacOS `top`, and the only change needed for Linux/Ubuntu is to replace the `-pid` with `-p`, as in `top (string split -n " " -- (printf -- "-p %s " (pgrep dart)))`.

Which works, but is quite verbose.  To simplify, you came up with:

```
top (string split " " -- "-pid "(pgrep dart)) # MacOS
top (string split " " -- "-p "(pgrep dart)) # Linux
```

Brilliant!  I've honestly never used [Cartesian Product](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/#combining-lists-cartesian-product) in `fish`, but that's clearly what you were going for in the first place with your brace-expansion attempts.

Using that example, I was then able to improve it (at least on Linux) to:

```
top "-p "(pgrep dart)
```

But I have a feeling that the equivalent `top "-pid "(pgrep dart)` isn't going to work on MacOS, since `top "-pid "{45, 23}` didn't work for you either.  That same construct (`top "-p "{1,11}`) works for me, for some reason.

Comment: This was really close, for macos I just had to modify it a bit: `top (string split -n " " -- (printf -- "-pid %s " (pgrep dart)))`.
I had to add in `--` a few times as I was getting errors that `printf` and `string split` were interpreting `-pid` as their own arguments.
The last thing I had to do was add in `-n` for `string split` so that there were no empty fields.
If you add what worked to your answer I'll accept. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I came up with a slightly less verbose command: `top (string split " " -- "-pid "(pgrep dart)) `

Comment: Ah, right - I ran across the issue with `-p` getting assigned to the wrong command, but putting the space before it worked for me.  `--` is the right answer, though, and clearly works in more cases.  Will update the answer soon.  Good to hear it got you in the right direction!

Comment: Hmm - How about just `top "-pid "(pgrep dart)`?  That works for me.(well, with `-p`, of course).

Comment: Nice one, i've accepted your answer. Unfortunately `top "-pid "(pgrep dart)` doesn't work on macos, probably because it joins "-pid " and each expanded pid into a single string (eg `"-pid 123" "-pid 124"`), where it needs to be split on the white space (eg `"-pid" "123" "-pid" "124"`). Still, great team effort and thank you for pushing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compose an expansion that results in every term of the expanded expression, when quoted, yielding a valid argument for `top`.

`"-pid "{45, 23}` looks, at first glance, as though it ought to be viable:

```
> echo "-pid "{45, 23}   
-pid 45 -pid 23
```

So, what's the problem ?  If we delimit the original expression and expand again:

```
> echo ["-pid "{45, 23}]
[-pid 45] [-pid 23]
```

Thus, the command-line you're generating for `top` using this expansion would be parsed like:

```
top "-pid 45" "-pid 23"
```

Instead, observe the following:

```
> p={45,23} echo [{-pid,$p}]
[-pid] [45] [-pid] [23]
```

As many things as `FiSH` does right, it does just as many wrong, so for no good reason whatsoever, the following isn't viable:

```
> echo [{-pid,{45,23}}]
[-pid] [45] [23]
```

Therefore, store your list of process id's in an array, and then use a brace expansion:

```
p=(pgrep dart) top {-pid,$p}
```